# Pulling data from edittext and comparing to charsequence

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to pull a line from an EditText and compare to a pin. If it's the correct pin it displays authorized, otherwise it displays it's the wrong pin. I can't get the 1234 to equal 1234 - it always says Pin Invalid.

```
Context context = this;
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Pin Entry");

final EditText pinEntry = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pinAuth);

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);

dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    CharSequence alertText;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    CharSequence pint = pinEntry.getText();

    if(pint != "1234")
    {
        alertText = "Pin invalid.\nPlease try again.";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
        updateList();
    }

    else if(pint == "1234")
    {
        alertText = "Pin authorized";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
    }   
dialog.dismiss();
}
});
dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
if(pint != "1234")
    {
        alertText = "Pin invalid.\nPlease try again.";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
        updateList();
    }

    else if(pint == "1234")
    {
        alertText = "Pin authorized";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

**to**

```
if(!(pint.equals("1234")))
    {
        alertText = "Pin invalid.\nPlease try again.";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
        updateList();
    }

    else if(pint.equals("1234"))
    {
        alertText = "Pin authorized";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, alertText, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> `pint.equals("1234")`

instead of

> pint == "1234"

You cannot use != and == for strings. These check the references rather than the actual contents of the string